# TypeScript correct way to type onChange handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple controlled input that looks like the following:

```
<textarea
  name="description"
  onChange={updateEdit}
  value={edit}
  placeholder={edit}
/>
```

my `updateEdit` handler

```
const updateEdit = (evt: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const updatedEdit: Edit = { id: proposalId, value: evt.target.value };
    dispatch(setEditForProposal(updatedEdit));
};
```

`Property 'target' does not exist on type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>'`

What's the correct way to type this?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
const updateEdit = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
```

The reason is you typed it as a `ChangeEventHandler`, which means a function that takes in a `ChangeEvent`. Or you could type the function as the handler

```
const updateEdit: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement> = (evt) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are typing the `React.ChangeEventHandler` in wrong place. should be

```
 const updateEdit: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>=(event){}
```

it is for handler itself but you are using for the argument of the function